# confusion about limit and big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $a_{n}$ be a real sequence, $b$ be a real number with $a_{n}$ converge to $b$. Consider the $a_{n}-b$, $a_{n}-b=O(1)$, but can $a_{n}-b=O(1/n^{c)}$, where $c>0$?

Clearly if $a_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$, then $a_{n}-b=O(1/n)$, what about $b\neq0$? Can the difference between converging sequence and their limit have a growth rate smaller than constants?(when the limit is not zero)

Comment: Yes, sequences can converge to their limits as fast as you like. Take any $f(n)$ that vanishes to $0$ at a particular order and define $a_n$ as $f(n)+b$.

Comment: @Jam When you said "sequences can converge to their limits as fast as you like", do you mean ALL sequences converge to limit as fast as I like, or does each sequence have its own converge rate?

Comment: @user517974 I mean that for every order of convergence, there is a sequence converging with that order. Of course, each sequence is limited to its own order of convergence.